# How to sign JAR files placed in the /WEB-INF/lib directory in maven

Tags: maven, sign

I want to use maven to sign all dependencies JAR files placed in the /WEB-INF/lib directory before created this web project as war file.

Could someone please give some suggestion how should i move forward?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [MWEBSTART plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/).

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
  <id>package</id>
  <phase>package</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>jnlp</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
   <codebase>${jnlp.URL}</codebase>
   <jnlp>
    <mainClass>${mainClass}/mainClass>
   </jnlp>
   <pack200>false</pack200>
   <sign>
    <keystore>${jks.filPath}</keystore>
    <keypass>${jks.keyPass}</keypass>
    <storePass>${jks.storePass}</storepass>
    <alias>${jks.alias}</alias>
    <verify>false</verify>
    </sign>
    <unsignAlreadySignedJars>true</unsignAlreadySignedJars>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```